# getting ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream error while using commons.fileupload with Equinox osgi

Tags: java, osgi, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to implement web plugin where i need file as an input. So i am using org.apache.commons.fileupload. It has internal dependency on org.apache.commons.io so included that in my plug-in as well as Bridge. But at run time am getting following error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [equinoxbridgeservlet] in context with path [/bridge]      threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream
at    org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at     org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:195)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:343)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
at sci2webbundle.UploadFile.doPost(UploadFile.java:122)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:91)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:110)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:115)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: On OSGI console i can see `31 ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.collections_3.1.0` and `212 RESOLVED    org.apache.commons.io_2.1.0` unable to understand why classNotFoundException !!!

Answer (score 0):

I did almost everything right. But i forget to add dependencies on imported Packages in `MANIFEST.MF` file. Just add `org.apache.commons.io.output` to dependencies thats it. It works :)